# How do you find the dual form of the class weighted soft-margin SVM?

Tags: svm

I am familiar with the dual form of the soft margin SVM when there is only one parameter $C,$ but I cannot find the dual form of the class-weighted soft margin SVM which has the following objective with parameters $C_1$ and $C_2$:

$$\frac12\Vert w\Vert^2 +C_1\sum_{\xi_i:y_i=-1}^l\xi_i +C_2\sum_{\xi_i:y_i=1}^l\xi_i$$

Can the dual form of this problem be derived?

Answer (score 0):

The bounds for the individual $\alpha_i$ are $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C_i$.